# What does a match statement look like in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and GTK and wrote a function with a long if/else if statement like so:

```
fn clicking_buttons(&mut self, button_name: String) {
  if button_name.eq("button_one") {
    self.on_btn_one();
  } else if button_name.eq("button two") {
    self.on_btn_two():
  } else if button_name.eq("button three") {
    self.on_btn_three():
  } else if button_name.eq("button four") {
    self.on_btn_four():
  } else if button_name.eq("button five") {
    self.on_btn_five():
  }
}
```

How would I write this using that Rust match statement?

Comment: What happens when you try to follow the examples here? https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html?highlight=match#the-match-control-flow-construct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rust
fn btn_one() {
    println!("Button one")
}

fn btn_two() {
    println!("Button two")
}

struct Button {
    name: String,
}

fn main() {
    let button = Button {
        name: String::from("one"),
    };

    match button.name.as_str() {
        "one" => btn_one(),
        "two" => btn_two(),
        _ => println!("Button not found!"),
    }
}
```